# How to count amount of digits in a given number in c++

Tags: c++, c

Count amount of digits in a given number or input by the user.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean.  If you ask a vague question people are unlikely to answer it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554521/how-can-i-count-the-digits-in-an-integer-without-a-string-cast

Comment: Hint (assuming this is homework) - divide the number by ten until you hit zero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Independent of programming language:

`floor(log10(x))+1`

where x is your number (>0).

If you want to handle 0 and negative numbers, I'd suggest something like this:

`x == 0 ? 1 : floor(log10(abs(x)))+1`

Comment: If `x==0` guard with an `if`, it's probably the best way to handle this, and put abs(x) inside the log to handle negatives, for which `log10` is undefined.

Comment: @cHao: That's a tricky question. How many digits are there in the float `float x = 1.0/3`? Not very useful either. If the OP is actually asking about non-integers, I'd surrender to the obvious: treating the user input as a string and checking its length (minus characters that we don't care about).

Comment: As for usefulness...yeah, it'd be kinda rare.  However, there'd be uses, mostly when doing formatted text output and such.

Answer (score 4):

Convert the number to a string and count the characters.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to know how many base 10 digits do you need to represent a binary number (such as an int).

```
double x = something(positive); 
double base = 10.0; 
double digits = ceil(log(x + 1.0) / log(base));
```