# Finding the scientific notation (E+XX)

Tags: c++, double, scientific-notation

I am trying to find the scientific notation with double and i could not find any function or way to do this.

My variable is double and I need to get the scientific notation from it, for example:

> 3.44828e+***026***

I need to somehow get the number ***026*** from my double variable.

By the way, the number is actually 28 long and not 26, is there a way to fix that too? (not adding 2 to the result)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're looking for the *logarithm*...

Comment: If the wrong exponent is displaying, you must be dividing the number by 100 before printing it. Computers don't usually get simple arithmetic wrong like that.

Comment: actually I am not dividing by 100.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to count amount of digits in a given number in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624490/how-to-count-amount-of-digits-in-a-given-number-in-c)

Comment: @NaorHadar Show us your code then.

Comment: double num = ((pow(10.0,28.0)-1.0)/29.0);
im printing num.

Comment: @NaorHadar `1e+28 - 1 = 9.99e+27`, if you divide it by `29` it will certainly be `3.xx e+26`. Why are you expecting `e+28` ?

Comment: @zakinster `1e+28 - 1` is `1e28` on most machines.  (Machine floating point values are _not_ real numbers, and don't obey the rules of real number arithmetic.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Good point, but on those machine, `1e+28 == 9.99e+27`, anyway that doesn't change the result, `1e+28 / 29 = 3.xx e+26`.

Comment: @zakinster Not a all.  On my Windows machine, for example, 1E+28 is actually 9.9999999999999996e+027, while 9.99E27  is 9.990000000000001e+027.  If I dump them, they have different binary representations.

Comment: @JamesKanze I didn't put all the `9` for the sake of readability, but of course I surely hope there's no system in which `9.99` actually equals `10` (the exponent not begin part of the significant precision). When I wrote `9.99e+27`, I actually meant `9.9999999...e+27`.

Comment: @zakinster A couple of dots after the 9.99 would have made that clearer.  I agree that lots of 9's don't help readability.  And the exact number you'd need will depend on the architecture.  (Also, the standard guarantees at least 10 digits for a `double`, so an implementation where `1e28` and 9.99e27` were equal wouldn't be conform.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if `y` is non-negative. For negative `y`, the result if off-by-one. Fix it yourself if needed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    double x = 3.44828e+026;
    int y = (int)log10(x);
    std::cout << y << std::endl;  
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `26`

Answer (score 1):

Answer similar to Yu Hao's but this one seems to work for negative exponents as well (but I haven't fully tested it):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

// pre-condition: x != 0.0
int exponent(double x) {
    double y = log10(x);
    if (y < 0.0)
        y -= 1.0;
    return static_cast<int>(y);

}

int main() {
    std::cout << exponent(3.44828e+026) << '\n';
    std::cout << exponent(3.44828e-026) << '\n';
}
```

Outputs `26` and `-26`.