# Count of characters in every node of list? (size of node in linked list)

Tags: java

This is mylist :

```
[675463645876543456746347543, 985769854789, 3456435]
```

I need to have something like below:

```
System.out.print(mylist.get(1));  ---> 675463645876543456746347543 and it is 27 digits
```

How can I show the size of every node?

Comment: what is the type of the objects in list?

Comment: Is the problem how to iterate over the list or how to calculate the size of each node?

Answer (score 2):

If you have Strings in your list, you could use ***length*** or you could convert int to String and use ***length*** but if you have integers and you don't want to convert read this: [How can I count the digits in an integer without a string cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/554533/211149). If you have integers I recommend you the second way.

Comment: @payam could you close the question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can just get each value in the list as a String and take the length of the String.

Answer (score 0):

Call toString method of each item and check the length of String.

```
System.out.print(mylist.get(1).toString().length() );
```