# I am trying to convert a string in decimal format to a number in lua

Tags: string, lua, int

I have 2 integer variables that I want to covert to a decimal integer. The result should be like this:

```lua
a = 10 
b = 12
c = 10.12
```

I can convert them with concatenate to a string decimal but then I cannot use math functions on the result. I have tried to use `tonumber()` on the string but I got a `nil` value.

Answer (score 1):

I assume in  the beginning `a` and `b` are integers and you wanted to join them so that `a` is the integer part of the resulting number and `b` is the decimal part - the part after the comma or dot in a double or float.

This is the string concat solution you suggested which works fine for me

```
a = 10
b = 12

c = tonumber(a..'.'..b)
print(c) -- prints 10.12
```

Here we are using math to calculate amount to divide `b` to get it as the correct decimal and then we add it to `a`. The code for determining the power of 10 was found here: [How can I count the digits in an integer without a string cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554521/how-can-i-count-the-digits-in-an-integer-without-a-string-cast)

```
a = 10
b = 12

c = a + b / math.pow(10, b == 0 and 1 or math.floor(math.log(math.abs(b), 10))+1)
print(c) -- prints 10.12
```

Comment: Using your first method I would also extract it to a function and add `assert`: `local function mergeToDecimal( a, b )
 local c = a .. "." .. b
 assert( tonumber( c ), "Could not convert number.")
 return c
end

mergeToDecimal( "10a", 12)`

Comment: This works sometimes, but b can be up to 4 digits. I am measuring temperature with a ds18b20 and it is returning a changing number of digits to b.

Comment: @RandyLust Did you use the first or the second approach when you tested and had the changing digits in b?
I changed the code very recently for the second approach because my math was wrong and only worked for the example case.

Comment: I used method 2.  c = a + b / math.pow(10, b == 0 and 1 or math.floor(math.log(math.abs(b), 10))+1)
print(c) -- prints 10.12   I had tried method 1 and got a nul.

Comment: Sorry I do not see a change in the math.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RandyLust Despite your example, I suspect by "a changing number of digits" (up to 4) that if a represents the whole number and b the fraction, you need something like: a + b/10000